# Percentage chance to make action

Tags: python, random

Simple problem:

```
percentage_chance = 0.36

if some_function(percentage_chance):
   # action here has 36% chance to execute
   pass
```

How can I write `some_function`, or an expression involving `percentage_chance`, in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could use [`random.random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.random):

```
import random

if random.random() < percentage_chance:
    print('aaa')
```

Comment: Great, now i have random.randrange(1,100) in range(1,int(chance*100)) but i don't think is this right.

Comment: random.random returns a floating point number, a continuous range, while randrange returns an int by default, so it's a set of discrete points within the range. If your percentage chance falls between the discrete points, it's like rounding it up or down to the nearest.

Answer (score 21):

```
import random
if random.randint(0,100) < 36:
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: it is better to use `randrange` function.

Comment: That comment needs qualifying `randrange` would change the behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

Just to make it more explicitly clear and more readable:

```py
def probably(chance):
    return random.random() < chance

if probably(35 / 100):
    do_the_thing()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code returns a 1, 36% of the time

```
import random
import math
chance = 0.36
math.floor( random.uniform(0, 1/(1-chance)) )
```