# adding a percent chance to display 1 message rather than the users input [Python}

Tags: python

Hey guys i am having some issues with implementing a random chance to display 1 thing instead of another. i have been adding and modifying a discord bot, metabot https://github.com/ikbenlike/metabot, with the creator and i had a new idea to add a funny message on the `!echo` command. this is in the metabot.py file

```
elif message.content.startswith('!echo'):
     if random.random() < percentage_chance:36
         command.comDont(client, channel, message)
     else:
         command.comEcho(client, channel, message)
```

in another file that it links, commands.py it has

```
def comEcho(client, channel, message):
    if message.author.id != client.user.id:
        input_ = message.content
        input_.split(" ")[0]
        args = input_.split(" ")[1:]
        client.send_message(message.channel, (" ".join(args)))

def comDont(client, channel, message):
    client.send_message(message.channel, "Don't Tell Me What To Say!")
```

it works without the random but i want to have that chance in there.
when i run the file it else is an invalid syntax. any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!
oh and i got the random.random from here [Percentage chance to make action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203099/precentage-chance-to-make-action)

Comment: Well your formatting is terrible so I could be mistaken, but it appears that you have an int 36 after your if statement. Is this correct or not?

Comment: What do you mean and yes 36 is the percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `random.random() < percentage_chance:36` seems like wrong syntax - try replacing it with something like `random.randint(1, 100) < 36:` (Both 1 and 100 are included).

Comment: I'll test that out soon

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked, the random.randint(1,100) <36:

Comment: @WillParker No problem, glad to help :-)